# SetWindowRgn в Delphi.

Tags: delphi

Что обозначает пeременная bRedraw в функции `SetWindowRgn(hWnd: HWND; hRgn: HRGN; bRedraw: Boolean);`

Answer (score 1):

```
int SetWindowRgn(
    HWND hWnd,  // handle to window whose window region is to be set
    HRGN hRgn,  // handle to region 
    BOOL bRedraw    // window redraw flag 
);
```

> Parameters
>
> hWnd
>
> Handle to the window whose window
> region is to be set.
>
> hRgn
>
> Handle to a region. The function sets
> the window region of the window to
> this region.  If hRgn is NULL, the
> function sets the window region to
> NULL.
>
> **bRedraw Boolean value that specifies whether the operating system redraws
> the window after setting the window
> region. If bRedraw is TRUE, the
> operating system does so; otherwise,
> it does not.  Typically, you set
> bRedraw to TRUE if the window is
> visible.**

Всего лишь нажал F1